# Proving that for a geometric distributed random variable $P(X\gt n+k−1|X\gt n−1)=P(X\gt k)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, distributions

I can reduce the left hand side to $(1−p)^k$. However, on the right hand side I am getting $(1−p)^{k−1}$. In the solution, the book shows the right side follows from the fact that; $P(X\gt k) = 1 - P(X\le k) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^k (1-p)^i p$

For a geometric distribution though isn't this incorrect? Shouldn't it be $1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (1-p)^i p$

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$P(X\gt n+k−1|X\gt n−1)=\frac{P(X>n+k-1 \cap X>n-1)}{P(X>n-1)}=\frac{P(X>n-1+k)}{P(X>n-1)}=P(X>k)$

**Key is event(set) $(X>n+k-1 \cap X>n-1)  $equal to Event(set) $(X>n-1+k)$**

This is the same as $(X>3 \cap X>2)=(X>3)$

For last equation use the memoryless property i.e

$\ P(N \gt n + m \mid N \gt m) =  \ P (N \gt n); \quad m, \, n \in \ N$

**As how to prove the memoryless property:**

For geometric distribution $F(x)=1-(1-p)^x$

$\ P(N \gt n + m \mid N \gt m) = \frac{\ P(N \gt n + m)}{\ P(N \gt m)} = \frac{1-P(N<n+m)}{1-P(N<m)}=\frac{(1 - p)^{n+m}}{(1 - p)^m} = (1 - p)^n = \ P(N \gt n)$

Ref [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/bernoulli/Geometric.html)